# Boolean query params are treated as strings and not transformed to boolean datatype

Tags: nestjs, supertest

I am running into an issue with supertest when a query parameter ({count: false}) is passed NestJS treats it as a string because the dto validation is not being executed.
test is

```
      it.only('should NOT return count if count is turned off', async done => {
    const result = await request(app.getHttpServer())
      .get('/setting/')
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')          
      .query({count:false})
      .expect(200)
    done();
  });
```

dto is

```
export class CollectionQueryDto {

  @IsOptional()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  afterId: any;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsOptional()
  @Transform((count, obj, type) =>
    obj.count.toLowerCase() === 'true' ? true : false,
  )
  count: boolean;

  constructor(partial: Partial<CollectionQueryDto> = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, partial);
  }
}
```

beforeAll is setup as follows

```
    beforeAll(async () => {
      const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
        imports: [
          SettingModule,
          SortationOrmModule,
          ConfigModule,
          GlobalOrmModule,
        ],
        providers: [SettingService, ConfigService],
      }).compile();
      app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
      service = moduleFixture.get<SettingService>(SettingService);
      await app.init();
      const rowsAffected = await loadConfigurationData(
        'TST.loadConfigurationData',
      );
    });
```

Main.ts has the validation pipe

```
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      transform: true,
      forbidUnknownValues: true,
      transformOptions: {
        enableImplicitConversion: true,
      },
      exceptionFactory: errors => new ClassValidationException(errors),
    }),
  );
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your test setup as well? Namely the `beforeEach/beforeAll` where you setup the `app` for testing?

Comment: I have added it above. Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: Last question, how is the validation pipe bound to the server? Is it route based or globally bound?

Comment: Globally bound. Thank you!

Comment: Now I understand why the transformation is not happening, so I am wondering how e2e tests are done when global validation is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your setup, you can add `app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe())` just like you do in `main.ts` so that pipes run for your e2e tests. You can do the same with interceptors, filters, and guards too.

Comment: Awesome, that worked. Thank you so much for answering and helping me think thru the process